# Merge two arrays and continue to increase row ids to avoid numeric gaps

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

You can see my case below

array first is like this :

=====================================================================

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#566 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "FIlZtX88m7B6mPykVjVUOEx652mSNP12H8u0yqBQ.jpeg"
  }
  1 => {#592 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"name": "b85irPvb4HCtNlytddpC055UYkTA53qMNW4AldT3.png"
  }
  2 => {#593 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"name": "CQSRte8sdcXEDSAodlT4MIJbnwHRqgMQpk7wzdjx.png"
  }
]
```

=====================================================================

array two is like this :

=====================================================================

```
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "jLKI9ySk58vGkdoIZEXVLHRMECCbRufhOlA0obrN.png"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "o82KG04rqlBTFkqf4WraVE5Gj9rbL1TB6SNKDHyd.png"
  ]
]
```

=====================================================================

I want to group 2 array to be like this :

=====================================================================

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#566 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "FIlZtX88m7B6mPykVjVUOEx652mSNP12H8u0yqBQ.jpeg"
  }
  1 => {#592 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"name": "b85irPvb4HCtNlytddpC055UYkTA53qMNW4AldT3.png"
  }
  2 => {#593 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"name": "CQSRte8sdcXEDSAodlT4MIJbnwHRqgMQpk7wzdjx.png"
  }
  3 => {#594 ▼
    +"id": 4
    +"name": "jLKI9ySk58vGkdoIZEXVLHRMECCbRufhOlA0obrN.png"
  }
  4 => {#595 ▼
    +"id": 5
    +"name": "o82KG04rqlBTFkqf4WraVE5Gj9rbL1TB6SNKDHyd.png"
  }
]
```

=====================================================================

Whether it can be done?

Comment: use array_merge($a, $b) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: @Captain, I know it. But that's not what I mean. You should read carefully. My case is somewhat different. See id when merged. See the form of both arrays and results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you can calculate the offset for id of the second array. Then use array_merge to get the result.

```
$offset = end($array1)->id;
array_merge($array1, array_map(function($v)use($offset){$v['id'] += $offset; return (object)$v;}, $array2));
```

Comment: It seems less a closing bracket

Comment: There exist error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`. The error in code row `$offset = end($array1)['id'];`

Comment: print_r your array here.

Comment: you can check it now

Comment: There still error. Like this : `Attempt to assign property of non-object`. The error in code row `function($v)use($offset){`

Comment: You array1 is array of object, and your array2 is array of array.

Comment: I edited my answer, I not realize your array have different structure.

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks. Sorry I can not give votes. Because my reputation is still under 15. So I can only accept your answer

Comment: yeah, glad it helps