# Merge two 2d arrays and ensure that newly added rows use the next available id value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

My code like this :

```
<?php 
    $a = array(
            array('id'=>1,'name'=>'chelsea'),
            array('id'=>2,'name'=>'mu')
    );
    $b = array(
            array('id'=>2,'name'=>'city'),
            array('id'=>3,'name'=>'liverpool')
    );
    $offset = end($a)['id'];
    $c = array_merge(
        $a, 
        array_map(
            function($v)use($offset){
                $v['id'] += $offset; 
                return $v;
            }, $b
        )
    );
?>
```

If the code run, the result like this :

> Array (
>
> [0] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 1
>               [name] => chelsea
>           )
>
> [1] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 2
>               [name] => mu
>           )
>
> [2] => Array
>               (
>                   [id] => 4
>                   [name] => city
>               )
>
> [3] => Array
>               (
>                   [id] => 5
>                   [name] => liverpool
>               )
>
> )

I want to change the result like this :

> Array (
>
> [0] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 1
>               [name] => chelsea
>           )
>
> [1] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 2
>               [name] => mu
>           )
>
> [2] => Array
>               (
>                   [id] => 3
>                   [name] => city
>               )
>
> [3] => Array
>               (
>                   [id] => 4
>                   [name] => liverpool
>               )
>
> )

How can I do it?

Note : The value on index `id` in array `$b` is dynamic. So the index `id` can have value between 1 - 5

Comment: Seems the same type of task as this question asked mere days earlier: [Merge two arrays and continue to increase row ids to avoid numeric gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44148064/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$offset = end($a)['id'];` to `$offset = end($a)['id'] - $b[0]['id'] + 1;`   [Live demo.](https://eval.in/814821)

Comment: If array `$b` like this : `$b = array(
            array('id'=>3,'name'=>'city'),
            array('id'=>5,'name'=>'liverpool')`, the order does not match

Comment: You want them offset by one.

Comment: when your `$a`'s id is 1, 3 , you code also not works.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work

```
    $a = array(
            array('id'=>1,'name'=>'chelsea'),
            array('id'=>2,'name'=>'mu')
    );
    $b = array(
            array('id'=>3,'name'=>'city'),
            array('id'=>5,'name'=>'liverpool')
    );
    $offset = end($a)['id'];
    // generate a new array with new ids based on array a 
    foreach($b as $value){
        $new_array[] =array('id'=>++$offset,'name'=>$value['name']);  
    }

    $c = array_merge($a,$new_array);
    print_r($c);
```